# wordpress ccavenue integration

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, ccavenue

I have installed the ccavenue plugin on my wordpress website with Woocommerce.I have even added the merchant id and the working key .

Shipping has been disabled because there needs no shipping option on the website.

Now the issue is as below :

- There is a 'NULL' on top of the ccavenue page that comes up

-once i click on proceed to payment,it redirects to the ccavenue page which has a section to fill out the shipping details,without having filled this,the form does not submit (i had disabled shipping methods) .

- Even after i fill out the shipping details,and i click on submit,the page does not show anything,neither success nor failure.

Please help .

Answer (score 0):

There is a select payment mode at the bottom of the page. Plase select the mode of the payment on the first ccavenue page you see and then hit submit. The plugin works fine for me with the same case.